# is there a way to share scripts in jenkins (not using PIPELINE)

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to have a shared script repo/library in Jenkins?

For example, there are building steps that run scripts I wrote. Instead of copying these script to each repo.. it would be nice to have a way to get them through one central place.

The only thing I found was:
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

but its for *pipelines* which isn't an option for me.

What workaround do I have?

Comment: So what type of jobs are u using? Are those shell scripts? How currently you are executing those?

Comment: they will be copied to each repository that the tasks run on

Comment: Have you looked at Git submodules?

Comment: Yup, git submodules should help you: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules . You can also keep it in one repo and in Jenkins do the additionall checkout of that repo which keeps scripts only. But still there is a question, what is the type of the job and how you execute it on Jenkins ?

Comment: @Chris Im not sure I understand the question, its a 'build' task. how I execute it? what do you mean

Answer (score 0):

We use [Managed Scripts plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/managed-scripts/) in order to share scripts between jobs. 
After installing the "Managed Scripts" plugin, you have a new option to create a managed script. These scripts can be reused in build steps in every job. Within the job, a user is able to select the required script from a drop-down menu.